# Errors in Four in a Row game in Java

Tags: java

I recently completed the code for a Four in a Row Game with 7 columns (represented by i below) and 6 rows (represented by j below), however, I keep getting out of bounds errors and I'm not sure why. If anyone can help spot and fix the errors, that would be awesome. Below is the code I have (the issues lie in the play, isGameOver and winner functions):

```
package hw4;

public class CFGame {
    //state[i][j]= 0 means the i,j slot is empty
    //state[i][j]= 1 means the i,j slot has red
    //state[i][j]=-1 means the i,j slot has black
    private final int[][] state;
    private boolean isRedTurn;

    {
        state = new int[7][6];
        for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<6; j++)
                state[i][j] = 0;
        isRedTurn = true; //red goes first
    }

    public int[][] getState() {
        int[][] ret_arr = new int[7][6];
        for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<6; j++)
                ret_arr[i][j] = state[i][j];
        return ret_arr;
    }

    public boolean isRedTurn() {
        return isRedTurn;
    }

    public boolean play(int column) {
        for(int j = 0; j < state[column].length; j++) {
            if(state[column][j] != 0 || state[column][j] < 0 || state[column][j] > 6 ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isGameOver() {
        for(int j = 0; j < state.length; j++) {
            for(int i = 0; i < state[j].length; i++) {
                if (state[i][j] != 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int winner() {
        //Checking horizontal win
        for(int j = 0; j < state.length; j++) {
            for(int i = 0; i < state[j].length-3; i++) {
                if(state[i][j] == state[i+1][j] && state[i][j] == state[i+2][j] &&
                        state[i][j] == state[i+3][j]) {
                    return state[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        //Checking vertical win
        for(int j = 0; j < state.length-3; j++) {
            for(int i = 0; i < state[0].length; i++) {
                if(state[i][j] == state[i][j+1] && state[i][j] == state[i][j+2] &&
                        state[i][j] == state[i][j+3]) {
                    return state[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        //Checking diagonal(s) win
        for(int j = 0; j < state.length - 3; j++) {
            for(int i = 0; i < state[j].length - 3; i++) {
                if(state[i][j] == state[i+1][j+1] && state[i][j] == state[i+2][j+2] &&
                        state[i][j] == state[i+3][j+3]) {
                    return state[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < state.length - 3; j++) {
            for(int i = 3; i <= state[j].length; i++) {
                if(state[j][i] == state[j+1][i-1] && state[j][i] == state[j+2][i-2] &&
                        state[j][i] == state[j-3][i+3]) {
                    return state[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

To me, the code seems fine but when I run it, it brings up the error.

If you spot any other mistakes, kindly let me know too.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: please add the resulted errors.

Answer (score 0):

You use index j and i differently in different loops. It looks like j should be the index for the first dimension and i is for the second, but you have `state[i][j]` in some places. That will definitely cause outofbound error because j can go as high as 6 but i is capped at 5 based on your code.

Comment: So would it be State[i][j] or State[j][i]?

Comment: It should be `state[j][i]` based on your for loops. I actually wrote a three in a row program for fun before. You could check it out here https://github.com/chungyang/tictactoe/tree/master/threeinarow. The class ThreeInARowGameBoard implements what you are trying to do. It checks if the win condition is met vertically, horizontally and diagonally.

Comment: If I may ask, for the purpose of learning, is it state[j][i] because j is in the outer for loop or because j represents rows? or both? As in, what determines whether it's [i][j] or [j][i]?

Comment: It's mainly because how you write your loop. Your outer loop checks the condition `j < state.length`. `state.length` returns the row dimension which is 7 in your code.